# Detectar cambios de un router en angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router

estoy tratando detectar cambios de la url pero no lo estoy logrando, hasta el momento tengo esto:

**homeComponent.ts**

```
constructor(private router: Router,private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit() {
   this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(url => console.log('The URL changed to: ' + url));
   this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => console.log('The URL changed to: ' + params["name"]));

   this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => { console.log(params) });
}
```

**homeComponent.html**

```
<app-navbarcust (logout)="logout()"></app-navbarcust>
<div class="container mt-5" [ngClass]='{"pt-5":true}'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

el `<app-navbarcust>` es el componente de la navegacion hay estan los **routerLink** sirven bien, esto me sale en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya cambie varias veces de ruta y no me salen las reacciones, alguien me podría por favor decir que estoy haciendo mal, otra pregunta no me estoy desuscribiendo en el ondestroy ¿esto esta mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te deberías subscribir en el ngOnInit, o en el constructor, yo la función que uso para detectar los cambios de ruta es el router.events y filtrando por NavigationEnd.

Y no esta mal que te desuscribas en el ondestroy, ya que si vuelves a cargar el componente, te volverá a subscribir al evento, y tendrás dos subscribers, pero tendrás que suscribirte asignándolo  a una variable para desuscribir ese mismo objeto.

```js
public subscriber: Subscription;

//en el constructor llamo mi router
constructor (private router: Router) {}

//En el ngOnInit, me subscribo al router events, que es el que te mandara los eventos cada que se inicie la navegación, y filtramos que solo te mande cuando termina de navegar NavigationEnd

ngOnInit () {
    this.subscriber = router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((event) => {
       console.log('The URL changed to: ' + event['url'])
    });
 }

  //En el onDestroy, valido si mi subscriber sigue activo y me desuscribo, si no seguirá activo escuchando cuando navegues a otro componente donde no lo requieras.
 ngOnDestroy () {
    this.subscriber?.unsubscribe();
 }
```